# Migrating from VMware to VirtualBox using ovftool.exe

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-workstation

I want to move my existing VMware virtual machine to the VirtualBox.
I do as described in https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/moving_a_vmware_vm_to

I'm trying to export my VMware virtual machine to OVF (Open Virtualization Format) using ovftool.exe tool:

```
E:\My Documents\Virtual Machines\CentOS>"C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware OVF Tool\ovftool.exe" CentOS.vmx OEL.ovf
```

But I get following error:

```
**Error: Failed to open file: CentOS.vmx
Completed with errors**
```

What's wrong here? Is there another way to create required OVF of VMware Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 1):

I tried different description on the internet and neither of them worked for me. In the end, I found one way that worked for me and I would like to share this one with you.

Important! First, I would like to mention that I did this only with test machines and never with a machine used in routine. I would not rely on a migrated VM for routine use.

I successfully migrated two Windows 2008 VMs using the following approach.

1. Uninstall VMware tools
2. Create a full clone of the VM to get a clean simple state without any snapshots. As a result, I have a VM with two virtual disk images, one single .vmdk file for each disk (C and D drive).
3. Create a new VM in VirtualBox without disks (Do not add a virtual hard drive).
4. Copy the virtual disk image files (vmdk) into the newly created VirtualBox VM folder. If you want, you can rename the disk files. I did that at this point, because, I wanted to have the disk type (C and D) reflected in the file name.
5. In VMware the disks were connected with a virtual SCSI adapter. The SCSI controller from VirtualBox for some reasons did not work with the virtual disks I had.
6. Therefore, I did open the settings of the just created VM, and added a IDE controller.
7. Then, I did choose to add a hard disk, and selected choose existing disk and selected the .vmdk file representing the first disk of the VM. Because, I had two disks, I did repeat this step once for the second disk. You also need to pay attention which on is disk 1 and which one is disk 2. If the OS is on disk 2, the VM will not boot.
8. Boot the VM. It should boot now. If Windows does not boot, because no BIOS, Windows, etc. found. Try to check, if your first disk is really the system disk.
9. Install the VirtualBox guest add-ons.

If other migration scenarios failed for you, you probably want to give this one a try.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/

I have used this for both physical to virtual and for older vmware vm's to virtual (both VB and ESXi 5) without issue. For Virtualbox, you should be able to install the tool and convert then move vmdk file to host and setup a new vm using the existing vmdk. I do not bother with import option in VB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you don't even need to convert them as VirtualBox can open VMX files without converting them. Just [follow the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505021/virtualbox-and-vmdk-vmx-files).